# Form with POST, how to get variable into Form

Tags: php, html, variables, post, get

I wanna make a form where the variables are gotten by the URL
My_url com/email.html?name=Myname

For example the name is introduced by default as "MyName"
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgBai.png)

How would could I do this?
The HTML code.
https://codepaste.net/sqq43i

The PHP code.

```
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['text'];

$mail_to = 'MyMail';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't use POST in that case, Instead use GET.

for ex:

```
$field_name = $_GET['name'];
$field_email = $_GET['email'];
$field_message = $_GET['text']; => the key here must be identical to the one in the url
```

the rest of your code should be the same assuming there is no syntax errors

Comment: I replaced all the POST for GET, still not working

Comment: PLs can you erase anything below this 3 lines of code and try to echo the $field_name like : echo $field_name and see if it prints the value you entred in the name input. if this worked than you have another problem

Comment: The 3 variable from the Form are shown in the next page, but I wanna have them in the Form before

Comment: Working now, just changed the ending from ".html" to ".php" and used this as input
 `code` <input name="name"  type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']); ?>" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name"  required/> `code`

Comment: I'm glad this helped

Answer (score -1):

just replace every place which is written `POST` with `GET` (both client and server)

like so:

```
$field_name = $_GET['name'];
$field_email = $_GET['email'];
$field_message = $_GET['text'];
```

and

```
<form class="form" action="form_handler.php" method="GET" id="form1">
```

Comment: Done it, but still not working http://prntscr.com/eg1jza

Comment: I tested my solution and it worked. double-check yourself.